# How do you compare the same day at same week for current year and previous year?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Most of the retailers, use a merch calendar for their sales report that can help them to find a same day at same week for current year and previous year.

For example today is **'2016-10-10' Monday**. For previous year; 2015, for same week, **Monday is '2015-10-12'.**

How can we catch this via query at SQL and show them in one table ?

Comment: In database work, *same week last year* is a fuzzy term. There's more than one way to define how weeks fall on a calendar year. SQL Server has a [SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634972.aspx) function, which is good to know about, but which might not do quite what you want.

Comment: What does *same week* mean to you? For your example, are you asking how to identify the second week in October in different years?

Answer (score 3):

You have all [date functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) to do it with long way:

- Figure out week number from date with [datepart week](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).
- Figure out day number from dates with [datepart weekday](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).
- Add weeks to `previous_year-01-01` with [dateadd week](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).
- Add difference days to it with  [dateadd day](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

Or shortcut just substracting 52 weeks it it is enough for you:

```
DATEADD(week, -52, some_Date)
```

Comment: Your shortcut assumes every year to have 52 weeks.

Comment: @Twinkles, yes, because this I say *'if it is enough for you'*

Comment: @danihp, this is not enough for me actually. As Twinkles mentioned , I also neet to catch the leap year.

Comment: 52 weeks from a Monday is still a Monday, regardless of leap year.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.data AS data1, t1.date AS date1,
  t2.data AS data2, t2.date AS date2
FROM table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table t2 
  ON ( DATEPART(week,t1.date) = DATEPART(week,t2.date)
     AND DATEPART(weekday,t1.date) = DATEPART(weekday,t2.date) )
WHERE DATEPART(year,t1.date) = 2016 
      AND DATEPART(year,t2.date) = 2015
```

If that query is too slow, you can assist it by using computed columns:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD year AS DATEPART(year,date) PERSISTED;
ALTER TABLE table ADD week AS DATEPART(week,date) PERSISTED;
ALTER TABLE table ADD weekday AS DATEPART(weekday,date) PERSISTED;

CREATE INDEX idx_datecalc ON table (year, week, weekday);
```

And now adapt above query:

```
[...]
LEFT OUTER JOIN table t2 
  ON ( t1.week = t2.week) ...etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply actually it seems ok right now but I had a really big data and this query is working around 4 hours or something like that.. I need a increase the performance. Do you have any suggestion to do that

Comment: Have you created the function based index I suggested?

Comment: CREATE INDEX function_index ON  and so on I guess

Comment: Ah, just realized SQL Server does not offer function based indexes. I will edit the answer.