# I'm trying to calculate variance using sql between two same days of two years

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I will try to be simple as possible to make my question crystal-clear. I have a table that's called 'fb_ads' (it's about different facebook compaigns for different stores in USA) on BigQuery, it contains the following columns:

- STORE : name of store
- CLICKS: number of clicks.
- IMPRESSIONS: number of impressions of the ad
- COST: the ad cost
- DATE: AAAA-MM-DD
- Frequency: number of visitors of a store

So, I'm trying to calculate the variance between two years 2017 and 2018.

Here is the variance I'm trying to calculate:

```
Variance_Of_Frequency = ((Frequency in 2018 at date X) - ((Frequency in 2017 at date X))/((Frequency in 2017 at date X)
```

The problem is, that I'll have to compare the same day of the week close to Date X;

For example, if I have a compaign run on a Monday 2017-08-13, I'll need to compare to another monday in 2018 close to 2018-08-13 (it might be a monday on 2018-08-15 for example).

This is a daily variance!

I tried to make a weekly variance calculating and I don't know if it's correct, here is how I did it:

I first started with aggregating my daily table to a weekly tables using the following query:

## creating my weekly_table

```
SELECT
  year_week,
  STORE,
  min(DATE ) as DATE ,
  SUM(IMPRESSIONS ) AS FB_IMPRESSIONS ,
  SUM(CLICKS ) AS FB_CLICKS ,
  SUM(COST) AS FB_COST ,
  SUM(Frequency) AS FREQUENCY,

FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    CONCAT(cast(ANNEE as string), LPAD(cast((extract(WEEK from date)) as string), 2, '0') ) AS year_week
  FROM `fb_ads`)
GROUP BY
  year_week,
  STORE,

  ORDER BY year_week
```

Then I tried to calculate the variance using this:

```
SELECT
  base.*, (base.frequency-lw.frequency) / lw.frequency as VAR_FF
FROM
  `weekly_table` base
JOIN (
  SELECT
    * EXCEPT (date),
    DATE_ADD(DATE(TIMESTAMP(date)) , INTERVAL 1 Week)AS date
  FROM
    `weekly_table` ) lw
ON
  base.date = lw.date
  AND base.store= lw.store
```

Anyone has any idea how to do the daily thing or if my weekly queries are correct ?

Thanks!

Comment: if you self join and match on `DATE_ADD(t1.date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) = t2.date` and the group based on week does that get you close to where you want? Don't treat dates as strings - something will be wrong. Sample input and output data would help a lot.

Comment: 2017-08-13 was a Friday. 2018-08-13 was a Monday :-(

Comment: @Strawberry , I just guessed hahaha.. just to illustrate what I'm looking for xD

Comment: @danblack, I believe my second query calculate the difference(variance) between two weeks in (a week and the next one) not two in different years :( ! Got any hint about the first one? Here is a question that looks almost the same but the guy worked with two different tables and it doesn't seem to be working for me! link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954784/how-do-you-compare-the-same-day-at-same-week-for-current-year-and-previous-year

Comment: For your suggested solution , I believe adding one year won't give us the same day of the week!

Answer (score 0):

For a given date, you want to know the date of the nearest Monday to the same date in the following year...

```
SET @dt = '2017-08-17';
SELECT CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(@dt + INTERVAL 1 YEAR) > 3 
            THEN ADDDATE(ADDDATE(@dt + INTERVAL 1 YEAR,INTERVAL 1 WEEK),INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(@dt + INTERVAL 1 YEAR) DAY) 
            ELSE ADDDATE(@dt + INTERVAL 1 YEAR,INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(@dt + INTERVAL 1 YEAR) DAY)
            END x;
```

Obviously, I could remove all those `+ INTERVAL 1 YEAR` bits by defining @dt that way to begin with.